# Does Data Connection support SSL Encrypted Oracle JDBC sources?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-data-connection

It looks like Oracle supports SSL encryption on its [JDBC connections](https://blogs.oracle.com/dev2dev/ssl-connection-to-oracle-db-using-jdbc%2C-tlsv12%2C-jks-or-oracle-wallets). Does this work using Data Connection?

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you have a JDBC driver that supports it. Just edit the JDBC URL manually, and set the flags appropriately.